# Why i cannot reshape of my numpy array derived from an image?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, image-processing, opencv

I have several PNG files in a directory, I am intended to read them into arrays and i want to flatten it. All images are grayscale images which is two channel image value like (28,28).

When i run this code

```
import numpy as np
import cv2,os,glob
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image

arrays_of_images=[]
data_paths = [os.path.join(pth, f) for pth, dirs, files in os.walk(path) for f in files]
for image in data_paths:
  img=Image.open(image)
  resized=img.resize((28,28))
  arrayed=np.array(resized)
  raveled=arrayed.ravel()
  arrays_of_images.append(raveled)
```

It turns me a list consist of arrays with (28,28) dimension. The total count of images are 736 when i turn the list into array i get (736,28,28) sized array. As you can see the `ravel()` function does not work. I want to flatten every image's array into (28x28) size and i want (736,28*28) sized array.

What is wrong with here? Why `ravel()` function does not work?

I have also tried `numpy.ndarray.flatten()` and it also does not work for me?

After that i will convert this array into pandas dataframe use `to_csv()` function, and will use it in K-nearest neighbor for image similarity detection.

Comment: I think you are better of using reshape for only flattening the two last dimensions: ```raveled=arrayed.reshape(736,-1)```

Comment: I used `reshape` with hundreds of different combinations. I have tried your answer too with `raveled=arrayed.reshape(784,-1)` it gave me (736,784,1) sized array. However, I've deleted 784 and rearrenged the code like this `raveled=arrayed.reshape(-1)` and it worked. Thank you for your answer it solved my problem.

Comment: You should confirm shape of each object in your process: `arrayed.shape`, `raveled.shape` and `arrays_of_images[0].shape`. Something somewhere is not as you assume. FYI, I followed your steps with 2 ppm images and was able to ravel `(28,28,3)` images to shape `(2352,)` and add to a list. When I convert the list to an array I get shape `(2,2352)`. BTW, Seems like a lot of work to save image data. Can't you save the images as nd.arrays? Do you need to flattened them to create a Pandas dataframe?

Comment: I can say that I was reinventing the wheel to see what's going on, what happens when you waste your time on inventing. I was trying to get (2352,) sized flatten pixel values of images into arrays. With my dataset I got (736,784) sized numpy array. Pandas df is completely to see whats happening. Next time i will try ndarrays to save time :). Thank you for your time and answer!